# Hidden Custom Post Type

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am just wondering is it possible to create a custom post type in wordpress which is hidden from the wordpress admin panel?

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be visible everywhere (i.e. search), just without the admin menu, then something to the effect of the following should do the trick when added to `functions.php` in the theme directory:

```
register_post_type( 'project',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Projects', 'post type general name', 'namespace' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Project', 'post type singular name', 'namespace' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add a New Project', 'namespace' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add a New Project', 'namespace' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Project', 'namespace' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Project', 'namespace' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Project', 'namespace' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Projects', 'namespace' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Nothing Found', 'namespace' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in Trash', 'namespace' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    ),
    'description' => "Projects",
    'public' => true, // All the relevant settings below inherit from this setting
    'exclude_from_search' => false, // When a search is conducted through search.php, should it be excluded?
    'publicly_queryable' => true, // When a parse_request() search is conducted, should it be included?
    'show_ui' => false, // Should the primary admin menu be displayed?
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false, // Should it show up in Appearance > Menus?
    'show_in_menu' => false, // This inherits from show_ui, and determines *where* it should be displayed in the admin
    'show_in_admin_bar' => false, // Should it show up in the toolbar when a user is logged in?
    'has_archive' => 'projects',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'project' ),
));
```

The Wordpress Codex about `register_post_type` contains more comprehensive information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 2):

[Yes, it is possible to register a non-public custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: As majorano84 says. Use public => false as argument when registering the custom post type.